# Why can't I set a view from a different ViewController view?

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LinkDetail", bundle: nil)
    var vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("red") as UIViewController
    containerView = vc.view
    println(vc.view)
    }
```

I know I have the view controller id set in storyboard to be "red". And when I println the output is:

```
<UIView: 0x7fbdc1e5a820; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbdc1e491b0>>
```

so the view must have been gotten correctly. So why can't I swap out my containerView UIView outlet with the view I get from code?

Comment: Is your containerView IBOutlet set correctly? What are the constraints on the views?  Try setting the background color of the containerView so that it stands out from your main view and ensure that it is visible and has an appropriate size

Comment: containerView.addSuvview(vc.view)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't holding a reference to the `vc` (red) view controller anywhere. The `containerView` is set to weak so nothing will retain the view that's being set on it.

I think you should be using [Child View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) in this case.

Using your snippet, this is how you would add the View Controller as a child:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LinkDetail", bundle: nil)
    var vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("red") as UIViewController
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    containerView = vc.view

    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// containerView = vc.view
containerView.addSuvview(vc.view)
```

Comment: Do you mean `containerView.addSubview` with a `b`?